# Passing a backslash string in Java gives me unicode error exception

Tags: java

I have Java code running

```
SparkAppHandle handler = 
    new SparkLauncher(options).setSparkHome("\usr\hdp\2.6.3.0-235\spark2");
```

I need to define the path as exactly like above but the compiler gives exception "Invalid Unicode"

Comment: In java strings, you have to escape the backslash character with another backslash , i.e `"\\usr\\hdp\\2.6.3.0-235\\spark2"` .

Comment: Don't use backslashes in a path

Comment: Use `File.separator` or `System.getProperty("file.separator");` instead. This will always provide the correct separator (\ for windows and / for *nix based systems).

Answer (score 3):

Escape \ using \\ inside Strings. Like this:

```
.setSparkHome("\\usr\\hdp...
```

Which becomes

```
\usr\hdp...
```

when you print it out, etc.